# MySQL JDBC Driver Using Flyway

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classpath, flyway

In my ~/.bashrc:

```
export CLASSPATH=~/mysqljdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
```

CLASSPATH var is correct:

```
ray@ubuntu:~$ echo $CLASSPATH
/home/ray/mysqljdbc/mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar
```

Trying to run it:

```
ray@ubuntu:/var/www/project$ sh ~/flyway-commandline-1.7/flyway.sh -driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -user=root -p=password -url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project init
Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.1.7

FlywayException: Unable to instantiate jdbc driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Occured in com.googlecode.flyway.core.util.jdbc.DriverDataSource.<init>() at line 93
```

Any ideas why it can't find the driver for this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've now changed the error message of Flyway Command-Line as well, to make this easier to spot and fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying -classpath or -cp overrides any setting of the CLASSPATH and this  is done in flyway.sh
According to  [flyway docs](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/) you have to store your mysql jdbc jar in jars folder (or just add it to JVM startup in flyway.sh).

Comment: guys I am getting the same error as  TJ but I am using maven.       <plugin>
              <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
              <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7</version>
              <configuration>
                <user>aa</user>
                <password>aa</password>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</url>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.googlecode.flyway:flyway-maven-plugin:1.7:migrate (default-cli) on project flywaydb: Flyway Error: com.googlecode.flyway.core.exception.FlywayException: Unable to instantiate jdbc driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -> [Help 1]